# Storyboard - how to make segues for a certain View

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

I got 2 views - containers on main view :
[image]

on the left - is a view - container for menu and behind it is a content container - also a view. It's simply a usual hamburger navigation

What I need is a storyboard with it segues to change a second view only - a content container. I'm new to iOS and presume that there could be a way to make storyboard for any view. Please tell me how to do it. If there should be any code - please write in Swift because I'm writing in it

Answer (score 1):

If your use case is: **Hamburger Navigation** should persist, you need to change the current FrontViewController for that. Segue will not be of use.

Segue is used for NavigationViewController. It will throw the controller to the new coming ViewController and Keep your Preview FrontViewController in its back stack.

Comment: Yes, I'm using xibs but looked for a way to use Storyboards  because it's much simpler

Comment: Segues can only be used with Storyboard, but delegates can be the way if you want communication between two view controllers.

Comment: yes, i'm using protocols/delegates, but it's so weird that you can't hang a storyboard on any view